# Adding jquery in Collabtive (open source project management)

Tags: jquery, smarty

I have no code to be shown. I just want to ask, is it possible to add some features with jquery in collabtive? I've tried to do this but jquery.js file looks like clash with the javascript in collabtive. Please help.

Thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean with "need server side"? I've tried to add simple feature in "add-user". I created the UI with jquery, but can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the cause of my problem. Collabtive has used other javascript library, `prototype.js`. So if we want to use jquery, we have to use `noConflict` because the `$` has been used.